# Why does discord.net sometimes run multiple times through code with a single instance?

Tags: c#, .net, discord.net

I am running a discord bot which hosts a game 24/7. Sometimes the bot runs some code double while it should only run it just once, which in my case causes a crash because it uses the same datareader at the same time. Problem is, I have looked through my code multiple times, and with multiple sets of eyes, but we cannot find a clue why it runs it double since it only should run it once. Some facts are:

- There is only one instance of the program.
- The code that is run twice is only called once in code.
- When the bot is restarted it is all fine, but after some time it happens again.

My feeling is that it has something to do with disconnecting and reconnecting to the discord servers. Because it mostly (maybe only) happens when the bot is idle for some time. I noticed that the bot periodically sends a 'Ready' message in the logchat, which it only does when it is restarted. But I cannot find a reason why, or how to fix it.

I have an example of what happens on discord, followed by a crash:

```
> MyBot BOT — 07/17/2021
> Not enough players (6/10) to start a game, trying again tomorrow 15:00.
> MyBot BOT — 07/18/2021
> @Inactief, Not enough players (6/10) to start a game, trying again at 15:30.
> @Inactief, Not enough players (6/10) to start a game, trying again at 15:30.
> @Inactief, Not enough players (6/10) to start a game, trying again at 15:30.
```

The last sentence is ran three times while it should only mention this once. This means that while there is only one instance running there seems to be going something wrong which means this method is called three times.

```
public async Task StartNewGame(string type, bool forced, bool speed, List<ulong> players = null)
{
    int playercount;

    if (players == null)
    {
        // here it gets the players, which works fine
    }
    else
    {
        playercount = players.Count;
    }


    if (playercount >= 10 || forced)
    {
        //some code
    }
    else
    {
        DateTime newtry;

        if (DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30).Hour < 20 || (DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30).Hour == 20 && DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30).Minute == 0))
        {
            newtry = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
            if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 15 && DateTime.Now.Minute < 30)
                await (_bot.server.GetChannel(_bot.gebeurtenischat.Id) as IMessageChannel).SendMessageAsync(_bot.Inactief.Mention + ", Not enough players (" + (playercount) + "/10) to start a game, trying again at " + newtry.ToString("HH:mm") + ".");
            else
                await (_bot.server.GetChannel(_bot.gebeurtenischat.Id) as IMessageChannel).SendMessageAsync("Not enough players (" + (playercount) + "/10) to start a game, trying again at " + newtry.ToString("HH:mm") + ".");
        }
        else
        {
            newtry = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day).AddHours(39);
            await (_bot.server.GetChannel(_bot.gebeurtenischat.Id) as IMessageChannel).SendMessageAsync("Not enough players (" + (playercount) + "/10) to start a game, trying again tomorrow " + newtry.ToString("HH:mm") + ".");
        }

        cmdText = string.Format("update servers set deadline = '{0}' where serverid = '{1}'", newtry.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), _bot.server.Id);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        await GetSpel();
    }
}
```

The only place where this code is called is at this piece of code:

```
DateTime deadline = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0][0]);

int ms = (int)(deadline - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;

if (ms > 0)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Waiting until " + deadline.ToLongTimeString() + " to start a new 
game.");
     await Task.Delay(ms);
}

await StartNewGame("All Any", false, false);
```

This is where the bot will idle when it is (re)started and waiting to start a new game. But it starts with one time going through, and after a night of sleep it happens to run twice or thrice at the same time through the code.

Has anyone experienced this, or does anyone know where to start looking for a solution?

P.S. Please let me know if you need any more details. This issue has been bugging me for months and I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Do you have any code being executed in a Ready event handler?

Comment: Yea I have, there I let the program get all the necessary values to the variables. It runs everytime the bot restarts right?

Comment: If the bot disconnects and reconnects without resuming the previous session, the Ready event will fire again. So any logic you have in there might end up running multiple times.

Comment: So disconnecting doesn't stop the previous session?

Comment: I don't mean disconnecting as in shutting down/rebooting. Discord periodically requests a gateway reconnect and when that happens  the bot would disconnect from the gateway and reconnect. It can reconnect and resume the existing session or sometimes it fails to resume. If it fails to resume the session, when it reconnects the ready event will fire again.

Comment: In short if you have logic in the ready event that should only run once, you should unsubscribe the ready event handler inside of the ready event. That way when it runs the first time (on boot) it will unsubscribe and even if the event fires again, the handler won't.

Comment: Yea I noticed the periodic request, but i had not thought about creating a new session and not stopping the last one. I moved my logic and I think it would fix the issue. Thanks for the help! And I will let you know!